# I want to remove cookies when the browser is closed but keep them while navigating between pages. How to do that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js

Hy, I want to delete all the cookies and local storage when closing the browser but want to keep the cookies and local storage while navigating between pages in nextjs.
I am using window.onbeforeunload event but this event is also triggered on navigating between pages. How to handle this issue.

Comment: Have you looked into SessionStorage? It is storage that lives to the duration of the tab/window.

Comment: So you are not using session cookies and session storage? No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yes I'm using session storage but I also need to remove local Storage and cookies on closing browser only. How can I do that?

Comment: There is no way to know.......... What you want to do is not possible. That is why you should be using the things built that handles it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned in comments you probably should use `sessionStorage`. See [Window sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) for more information. Cool thing about it is that it deletes data after the session ends. But you can also delete session data within the session if you wish.

Edit:
You could handle cookie and local storage data deletion on your own (when the browser is closed). Do this after you've stored whatever you need in `sessionStorage`. Then when you navigate around you'll still have that data in `sessionStorage` regardless of whether cookies or ls have it.

Comment: Yes I'm using session storage but I also need to remove local Storage and cookies on closing browser only. How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe I'm not clearly understanding what you're looking for. `sessionStorage` should persist your data across page navigation and when you close the browser, all data should be deleted (`sessionStorage` will delete that data automatically and you can delete the rest on your own).

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. The method I'm using is I'm checking if the sessionStorage is active then don't call the handleAllSessions function to remove the cookies otherwise call it.

```
    if (
    typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
    !sessionStorage.getItem('sessionActive')
  ) {
    handleAllSessions();
  }
  function handleAllSessions() {
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem('sessionActive')) {
      document.cookie = 'suauth=; expires=2000-10-16T19:22:35.000Z;';
      localStorage.removeItem('isAuthenticated');
    }
  }
```